# how to pass to pages after login?

Tags: java, jsf

i am trying to pass to index.xhtml through login.xhtml which it works . the problem that the login page appear any time i ask for any page . i don't understand what should i correct . 
this is login.xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid styleClass="panelGridCenter" columns="2" cellpadding="5">

        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email" />
        <p:inputText id="email" name="email" label="email"
            required="true" value="#{loginBean.email}" requiredMessage="le champ username est obligatoire"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Mot de passe:" />
        <p:password id="password" name="pw" label="Mot de passe"
        required="true"  value="#{loginBean.password}" requiredMessage="le champ mot de passe est obligatoire"/>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Login" action ="#{loginBean.login}">
            </p:commandButton>
            <h:outputLabel for="inscrit" value="Vous n’avez pas de compte ?" />
            <p:commandLink id="ins" immediate="true" action="#{loginBean.register}" ajax="false">
                <h:outputText value="Inscription" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

and thid is LoginBean.java

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {
    @Inject
    private LoginServiceImpl loginServiceImpl;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String login() {

        User user = loginServiceImpl.login(email, password);
         if (user!=null) {

                HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("email", email);

                return "index";
            } else {

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                        "Invalid Login!",
                        "Please Try Again!"));


                return "login";
            }
        }
public String register(){
    return "AjoutUser?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Util.java

```
public class Util {
     public static HttpSession getSession() {
            return (HttpSession)
              FacesContext.
              getCurrentInstance().
              getExternalContext().
              getSession(false);
          }

          public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
           return (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.
              getCurrentInstance().
              getExternalContext().getRequest();
          }

          public static String getUserName()
          {
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            return  session.getAttribute("email").toString();
          }
```

faces-config.xml

```
 <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Have you enclosed your code by `<h:form>` tag ?

Comment: why are you using the `navigation-rule` tag in `faces-config`? using the `action` attribute on the command button and the `return` values on you managed bean method should suffice.

Comment: if i enclode  the code by <h:form> even the authentifaction doesn't work .

Comment: even when i delete the navigation-rules the problem persist .

Comment: do you know how can i make a user login until he logout ?